# Fourier series of given function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I need to find the fourier series for the folowing function:
$f(x)=x+1, -1\leq x <0\\ \hspace{1.4cm} 1-x, 0\leq x <1$

I end up with just the first coefficient $a_0$ being 1/2 and $a_m=0$ and $b_m=0$. This answer is wrong according to the solutions, but I can't figure out what I did wrong. Could someone help me with this problem?
[My try to solving the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHhzv.jpg)

Comment: What does "x+" mean ?

Comment: That was a typo, I apologize. It's changed to x+1

Comment: Yes Peter. I'm new to this website and new to this way of formatting aquestion. Again my apologies, the question should be correct right now

Comment: OK, how did you conclude that $a_m=b_m=0$ (except $a_0=\frac{1}{2}$) ?

Comment: I computed $a_m = \int_{-1}^0{(x+1)cos(m\pi x)dx} + \int_0^1{(1-x)cos(m\pi x)dx}$ and $b_m = \int_{-1}^0{(x+1)sin(m\pi x)dx} + \int_0^1{(1-x)sin(m\pi x)dx}$, since $L=1.$ I provided a picture with my notes in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x) = 1-|x|, x \in [-1,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere

$f(x) = \frac 12 a_0 + \sum a_n \cos n\pi x + b_n \sin n\pi x$

$a_0 = \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \;dx = 1$ which you have already found

$a_n =$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) \cos n\pi x \;dx \\ 
\int_{-1}^1 \cos n\pi x \; dx + \int_{-1}^0 x\cos n\pi x\;dx  + \int_{0}^1 -x\cos n\pi x \;dx\\
\frac {sin n\pi x}{n\pi} |_{-1}^{1} + (\frac {x \sin n\pi x}{n\pi} + \frac {\cos n\pi x}{n^2\pi^2})|_{-1}^0 - (\frac {x \sin n\pi x}{n} + \frac {\cos n\pi x}{n^2})|_{0}^1$

Evaluating this, it is worth noting the following:

$\sin n\pi=0$

if $n$ is even $\cos n\pi = cos 0$

if $n$ is odd $\cos n\pi = -1$

Using this information, it falls into place that:

$a_n = 0$ if $n$ is even.

$a_n = \frac {4}{n^2\pi^2}$ if $n$ is odd.

$b_n =$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) \sin n\pi x \;dx$

$b_n = 0$  Now I could go through all of the integration and it would look not entirely dissimilar to the how we found $a_n.$  However, $f(x)$ is an even function.  The Fourier series will be the sum of a set of even functions.

Comment: It would be nice if you would mention at least the first few terms of the expansion.

Comment: Doug, should the last component of your third line $\frac{x\sin n\pi x}{n \pi} + \frac{\cos n \pi x}{n^2 \pi^2}|_0^1$? If I work it out from there, I'll get this:

Comment: $a_n=\frac {sin n\pi x}{n\pi} |_{-1}^{1} + (\frac {x \sin n\pi x}{n\pi} + \frac {\cos n\pi x}{n^2\pi^2})|_{-1}^0 - (\frac {x \sin n\pi x}{n \pi} + \frac {\cos n\pi x}{n^2 \pi^2})|_{0}^1=\\0+(\frac{x \sin \pi x}{n\pi} + \frac{\cos n \pi x}{n^2 \pi^2}|_{-1}^0 - \frac{x\sin \pi x}{n \pi} + \frac{\cos n \pi x}{n^2 \pi^2}|_0^1=\\ \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}-\frac{\cos n \pi}{n^2 \pi^2}-(\frac{\cos n \pi}{n^2 \pi^2} - \frac{1}{n^2 \pi^2}=\\\frac{2}{n^2\pi^2}$

Comment: Revision to my previous comment:  
$a_n=\frac {sin n\pi x}{n\pi} |_{-1}^{1} + (\frac {x \sin n\pi x}{n\pi} + \frac {\cos n\pi x}{n^2\pi^2})|_{-1}^0 - (\frac {x \sin n\pi x}{n \pi} + \frac {\cos n\pi x}{n^2 \pi^2})|_{0}^1=\\0+(\frac{x \sin \pi x}{n\pi} + \frac{\cos n \pi x}{n^2 \pi^2}|_{-1}^0 - \frac{x\sin \pi x}{n \pi} + \frac{\cos n \pi x}{n^2 \pi^2}|_0^1=\\ \frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}-\frac{\cos n \pi}{n^2 \pi^2}-(\frac{\cos n \pi}{n^2 \pi^2} - \frac{1}{n^2 \pi^2}=\\\frac{2}{n^2\pi^2}) + \frac{2}{n^2 \pi^2}$ (if n is odd). After some time I got the answer, thank you for helping me out!

Comment: if $n$ is even $\cos n\pi x = \cos 0$ and $(\cos n\pi x)|_{-1}^{0} = \cos 0 - \cos 0 = -(\cos n\pi x)|_{0}^{1}.$  If $n$ is odd $\cos n\pi x = -\cos 0$ and$(\cos n\pi x)|_{-1}^{0} = \cos 0 - (-\cos 0) = 2 = -(\cos n\pi x)|_{0}^{1}$